# No Plymouth splash screen after upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: nvidia

I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 and got only a fleeting glimpse of the Plymouth Ubuntu 12.10 in text, not the logo, when booting up.
A black screen flashed then a blank purple screen shows at which point I got the quick glimpse of the Plymouth Text, if if I was lucky enough to see it all. Strange, because when I first upgraded it worked fine. At no point since the upgrade, however has the Shutdown screen shown the Plymouth logo, Now all I see is a purple screen with some white text and a cursor flashing on the left hand side. The text reads as follows:

> Ubuntu 12.10 OK
> Killing all remaining processes FAIL (in red letters)

I posted this problem in Launchpad and was given the following advice; I was to run this command in the Terminal

```
sudo lshw -C display; lsb_release -a; uname -a
```

and give the output from it, which was as follows:

> *-display
> description: VGA compatible controller
> product: GT216 [GeForce GT 220]
> vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
> version: a2
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
> configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
> resources: irq:16 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff
> ioport:2000(size=128) memory:d3080000-d30fffff No LSB modules are
> available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 12.10 Release:
> 12.10 Codename: quantal Linux debbie-GT5042B 3.5.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 13 17:49:53 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Then I was told to give the output of

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

which was

> ii nvidia-common 1:0.2.71.1 i386 transitional package for ubuntu-drivers-common
>
> ii nvidia-current 304.51.really.304.43-0ubuntu1 i386 NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
>
> ii nvidia-settings 304.51-0ubuntu2 i386 Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver

Then I was told the answer to all this would be to run the following into the Terminal;

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current nvidia-settings
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This has made no difference whatsoever, I still get the flashing black screen at startup and the text, with processes shutdown when I turn off my computer; in other words still no logo. This was the output from the Terminal when I ran the above commands;

```
debbie@debbie-GT5042B:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current nvidia-settings

[sudo] password for debbie:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libept1.4.12 libvte-common libvte9
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  nvidia-current* nvidia-settings*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 112 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 171797 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-current ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf to auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf to auto mode
INFO:Disable nvidia-current
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Processing quirk ThinkPad T420s
DEBUG:Failure to match GATEWAY with LENOVO
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
DEBUG:Processing quirk Latitude E6530
DEBUG:Failure to match GATEWAY with Dell Inc.
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Purging configuration files for nvidia-current ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing nvidia-settings ...
Purging configuration files for nvidia-settings ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic

debbie@debbie-GT5042B:~$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  dkms* fakeroot* libept1.4.12* libvte-common* libvte9* screen-resolution-extra*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,680 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 171566 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing dkms ...
Purging configuration files for dkms ...
Removing fakeroot ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-tcp to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
Purging configuration files for fakeroot ...
Removing libept1.4.12 ...
Purging configuration files for libept1.4.12 ...
Removing libvte9 ...
Purging configuration files for libvte9 ...
Removing libvte-common ...
Removing screen-resolution-extra ...
Purging configuration files for screen-resolution-extra ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

debbie@debbie-GT5042B:~$ sudo apt-get clean

debbie@debbie-GT5042B:~$ sudo apt-get update

Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release [49.6 kB]
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release [49.6 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources [19.5 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources [14 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources [6,763 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources [695 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages [54.8 kB]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages [16.8 kB]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,394 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en [26.4 kB]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_GB
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en_GB
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_GB
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en [9,362 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Get:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources [49.2 kB]
Get:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources [889 B]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources [21.9 kB]
Get:18 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources [2,940 B]
Get:19 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages [126 kB]
Get:20 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages [1,979 B]
Get:21 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages [66.1 kB]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Get:22 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [8,121 B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en_GB
Get:23 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en [62.6 kB]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
Get:24 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en [39.2 kB]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_GB
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en_GB
Fetched 615 kB in 4s (154 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

debbie@debbie-GT5042B:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dkms fakeroot nvidia-settings screen-resolution-extra
Suggested packages:
  dpkg-dev debhelper
The following NEW packages will be installed
  dkms fakeroot nvidia-current nvidia-settings screen-resolution-extra
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 40.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 113 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main dkms all 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu1 [72.8 kB]
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main fakeroot i386 1.18.4-2 [88.0 kB]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/restricted nvidia-current i386 304.51.really.304.43-0ubuntu1 [38.1 MB]
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main screen-resolution-extra all 0.15 [13.1 kB]
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main nvidia-settings i386 304.51-0ubuntu2 [1,803 kB]
Fetched 40.1 MB in 26s (1,529 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 171431 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dkms (from .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Unpacking fakeroot (from .../fakeroot_1.18.4-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-current.
Unpacking nvidia-current (from .../nvidia-current_304.51.really.304.43-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package screen-resolution-extra.
Unpacking screen-resolution-extra (from .../screen-resolution-extra_0.15_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-settings.
Unpacking nvidia-settings (from .../nvidia-settings_304.51-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.18.4-2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
Setting up nvidia-current (304.51.really.304.43-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libOpenCL.so because associated file /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 because associated file /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libvdpau_nvidia.so because associated file /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-current/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-current
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Processing quirk ThinkPad T420s
DEBUG:Failure to match GATEWAY with LENOVO
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
DEBUG:Processing quirk Latitude E6530
DEBUG:Failure to match GATEWAY with Dell Inc.
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
Loading new nvidia-current-304.43 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.5.0-19-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.5.0-19-generic
Done.

nvidia_current:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-19-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up screen-resolution-extra (0.15) ...
Setting up nvidia-settings (304.51-0ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/nvidia-settings/ld.so.conf because link group nvidia_settings_conf is broken
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
debbie@debbie-GT5042B:~$
```

Since this hasn't worked, is there any way of reversing what I've done in the terminal?
Is there someone out there who can help with this problem?
My post in Launchpad at the moment has become stagnant and I'm wanting to get this sorted out.

Many thanks,

Debbie

Answer (score 1):

Use the hardware drivers, GUI installer, in Ubuntu. You may have different successes, depending on which driver you choose. Such as you might increase FPS in games, but lose hibernation.

This is why Nvidia should open source their drivers. Open drivers have advantages. Proprietary driver/modules have differing ones.

Then also do the following:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml

The last time I did Plymouth, with Ubuntu, Ubuntu made it extremely difficult to do any other theme, but the Ubuntu standard (per release) start-up, graphic theme. If you get that deep, some themes (for Ubuntu) work, and some do not.